# Whats the best practice of using subscripts in symbols?

Tags: symbols

I have stumbled over several issues about subscripted symbols recently.
I would like that I can enter subscripted variables with my keyboard and that they are treated as symbols. I would also like to have lists (matrices) of these subscripted symbols and that they are formatted in the output nicely so that I can do calculations which them and still be able to see the nice output.

**So far I have come up with the following (which uses the Notation Package):**

```
Needs["Notation`"];

Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubsuperscriptBox["_", "_", "_"]]]

makeSpecialSymb[var_String, i_, j_] := 
  ToExpression[SubscriptBox[var, ToString[i], ToString[j]]];

makeSpecialSymb[var_SubscriptBox, i_, j_] := 
  ToExpression[
   SubscriptBox[var[[1]], 
    var[[2]] <> "," <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j]]];


makeSpecialSymb[var_SubsuperscriptBox, i_, j_] := 
  ToExpression[
   SubsuperscriptBox[var[[1]], 
    var[[2]] <> "," <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j], var[[3]] ]];

SymbolicMatrix[func_Function, m_Integer, n_Integer] :=
  Table[func[i, j], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];

SymbolicMatrix[func_Function, m_Integer] :=
  Table[func[i], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, 1}];

SymbolicMatrix[argSpecSymb_, m_Integer, n_Integer] :=
  Table[makeSpecialSymb[argSpecSymb, i, j], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];

SymbolicMatrix[argSpecSymb_, m_Integer] :=
  Table[makeSpecialSymb[argSpecSymb, i], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, 1}];
```

**So i can do the following:**

```
A = Map[HoldForm, SymbolicMatrix["W", 2, 2], 2];
B = SymbolicMatrix[SubsuperscriptBox["G", "S", "k"], 2, 2] ;
A // FullForm
B // MatrixForm
?"Global`*"
```

[image]

**So everything works fine, I can make a Matrix out of Symbols which are defined in the global context and which get formatted really nice. This is cool!**

Another approach would be something (from [Mike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36974/7609)), where we do not generate the symbols but rather use some sort of formatting expression like the following:

```
 ClearAll[fancySubscript1];

SetAttributes[fancySubscript1, HoldFirst]

fancySubscript1 /: 
 MakeBoxes[fancySubscript1[var_, index_], StandardForm] := 
 SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes[var, StandardForm], 
  StyleBox[RowBox[{MakeBoxes[var, StandardForm], 
     MakeBoxes[index, StandardForm]}], ZeroWidthTimes -> True]]

fancySubscript1[var_, indices : {_Integer ..}] := 
 fancySubscript1[var, #] & /@ indices


fancySubscript[H, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

**Which gives:**
[image]

If I would go with this method, which prints all values very nicely, I can make matrices which do not contain symbols but rather function expression.
In this method I am probably also much more flexible when I want to define my own look how the individual fancySubscripts are formatted.

Which version would you go for in which cases? I am a bit unsure, which one of these is better to use, also with respect to flexibility.
Also with respect to what method is better to use for if I want to replace the variables with values in subsequent calculations (either by replacement rules or by Set[] ) ?

Another question for method 1, how does mathematica decide how to display my crazy named variables like: `W\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]1` in the output? It seems that all symbols, which get created by the `ParsedBoxWrapper` which I think gets called when ever it sees a `SubscriptBox` pattern as defined in the `Symbolize` command, are displayed nicely.
If I enter `RR\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]100` in a new notebook it does not immediately get converted to a nice subcripted output format? Whats the problem here?

I would be really interessted what the caveats are in these two methods, because I am not kind of a hero with mathematica.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me like the Notation package lets `$PreRead` parse your custom notations and interprets your custom symbols before sending to the kernel. If your code generates a subscripted expression in the kernel, then `$PreRead` doesn't have a chance to convert it before the kernel passes it on to the next function. Similarly, I think `$PrePrint` converts the crazy named variables into your pretty notation.

Comment: When you use `Symbolize` the rules are added to the `$PreRead` and `$PrePrint` definitions, so the crazy names that you enter directly don't get caught by the `Symbolize` pattern, so the `$PreRead` and `$PrePrint` rules don't get created.

Comment: Using the Notation package defeats many of the advantages of using subscript notation in the first place ... namely being able to run through the $x_i$ with Do or Table or pattern matching. I avoid it entirely as the antithesis of mma design.

Comment: The best practice to using Subscripts is to not use them =)

Comment: I must admit not having read the whole post, so sorry if this isn't appropriate. I would suggest symbolizing the subscripts only if you are really in need of them being treated as symbols. Otherwise, use some private head and make it format as subscript.

Comment: Some issues with subscripts are discussed in these answers to the [Pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393) and links contained in them: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/57), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562)